# Java elements arangement

Tags: java, button, user-interface, applet

I have the following code. If i maximize the window of the applet, all the elements will be ordered on a single line. I would like to have some elements on a line and other on another line and so on. I tried to create panels but it doesn't work. What should I change in order to solve this problem ?

```
import java.applet.Applet;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;


public class Numbers extends Applet implements ActionListener{
private Button b1,b2,b3;
private Label lb1,lb2,lb3;
private TextField tf1,tf2,tf3;
private Panel row1,row2,row3,row4,row5;
private Panel CreatePanel(LayoutManager layout_type)
{
 Panel p=new Panel();
p.setLayout(layout_type);
return p;           
}
public void init() {
    setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEFT,4,2));
    row1=CreatePanel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER,4,2));
    lb1=new Label("First number: ");
    tf1=new TextField("",10);
    row1.add(lb1);
    row1.add(tf1);
    add(row1);
    row2=CreatePanel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER,2,2));
    lb2=new Label("Second number: ");
    row2.add(lb2);
    tf2=new TextField("",10);
    row2.add(tf2);
    add(row2);
    row3=CreatePanel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER,4,2));
    b1=new Button("Multiply ");
    b1.addActionListener(this);
    row3.add(b1);
    b2=new Button("Add");
    b2.addActionListener(this);
    row3.add(b2);
    b3=new Button("Subtract");
    b3.addActionListener(this);
    row3.add(b3);
    add(row3);
    row4=CreatePanel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER,4,2));
    row5=CreatePanel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER,5,2));
    lb3=new Label("Result:          ");
    row5.add(lb3);
    add(row5);
    }
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
    String txt1=tf1.getText();
    String txt2=tf2.getText();
    int n=Integer.parseInt(txt1);
    int m=Integer.parseInt(txt2);
    if(e.getSource()==b1)
    lb3.setText("Result: "+n*m);
    if(e.getSource()==b2)
        lb3.setText("Result: "+(n+m));
    if(e.getSource()==b3)
        lb3.setText("Result: "+(n-m));               
    }



    }
```

Comment: `FlowLayout` arranges the components side by side. If there is no space then moves the components to the next line. It's default behavior of `FlowLayout`.

Comment: What layout manager should I use ?

Comment: Find it here [A Visual Guide to Layout Managers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html)

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: On the first line a label and a text field, on the second the same, on the third three buttons and on the fourth one label (result label)

Comment: `row4` is not used at all in your code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try with [GridLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/GridLayout.html) as root panel and add all other panels in it.

> Read more about [A Visual Guide to Layout Managers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html) where it is explained with sample code as well.

Sample code:

```
public void init() {
    Panel rootPanel = CreatePanel(new GridLayout(4, 1)); // 4 rows with 1 column
    ...
    rootPanel.add(row1);
    ...
    rootPanel.add(row2);
    ...
    rootPanel.add(row3);
    ...
    rootPanel.add(row5);

    add(rootPanel);
}
```

Note: Always follow [Java Naming Convention](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/variables.html)

Comment: Not a all. You're most welocme